# Spellcheck on Bound vs Unbound and Parent vs Sub forms - Second Update

Tags: spell-checking

I know Spellcheck in Access has been talked ad-nauseum in this and many other forums so I apologize for resurrecting a dinosaur, but I just could not find an answer anywhere. This forum has been invaluable to me and for that I thank all those whose posts I have read and learned from.

For several months I have been trying to get Spellcheck working in an Access system I built. I have it mostly working but am tearing what little hair I have left over the following scenario. I apologize in advance for likely not framing the problem very well.

I have a simple query Bound form (Form B) that allows the user to select/edit/add/delete records. It has a mix of control types. I have added a cmd button to the form with the following code behind it and if I invoke this form directly – it works fine all day long and checks the Text Boxes on the form without complaint.

```
Private Sub SpCk_Click()
  Me.SetFocus
  DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSelectRecord
  ‘    DoCmd.SetWarnings False      ‘commented to allow error msgs.
  DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSpelling
  DoCmd.SetWarnings True
  MsgBox ("Spellcheck completed - be sure to save any changes made.")
End Sub
```

I have what I call a dispatcher form (Form A) that allows the user to invoke one of several different forms for different tasks and it uses a command such as the following to do so:

```
Private Sub FormB_Click()
  DoCmd.OpenForm "Form B", acNormal, "", "", , acNormal
End Sub
```

Now, if I invoke Form B from Form A, select a record, and try to run spellcheck against it, the spellchecker tries to run against **Form A** and not Form B. It fails because there are no Text Boxes on Form A, only command buttons. If I close Form A and then try to run spellcheck again on Form B, spellcheck re-activates Form A and tries/fails again. If I close both and then re-invoke Form B directly – all is good again.

Now, here is where it gets even weirder. I have another Unbound form (Form C) that allows the user to create a new record and insert it into a table and it works perfectly no matter how it is invoked (i.e. directly or via Form A). I’ve tried everything I can think of but I’m out of ideas. HELP

Sorry for being so wordy but I didn’t know any other way to tee this up for some help and humble TIA for any that comes my way.

UPDATE: I've done more checking - Bound vs Unbound makes no difference so it must have to do with the way the form is invoked.
UPDATE: Out of curiosity and desparatation I added the line
*DoCmd.SelectObject acform, "Form B"*
after the OpenForm command and that seems to have solved many (but not all) of my problems. Why? I wish I completely understood why, but I'm taking a victory lap anyway.